# Is there a finite axiomatization of Tarski's geometry axioms?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, first-order-logic, axioms, axiomatic-geometry

[Tarski's geometry axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms) include an axiom schema, the axiom schema of continuity. Let $\phi(x)$ be a first order formula not containing $y$, $a$, or $b$ as free variables. Let $\psi(y)$ be a first order formula not containing $x$, $a$, or $b$. Then

$$[\exists a \forall x \forall y ([\phi(x) \land \psi (y)] \implies Baxy)] \implies [\exists b \forall x \forall y ([\phi(x) \land \psi (y)] \implies Bxby)]$$

This means that Tarski's axioms has infinitely many axioms.

Is there a way to reduce Tarski's axioms to a finite list of equivalent axioms?

Comment: From the last couple lines of that wikipedia article: "This schema is indispensable; Euclidean geometry in Tarski's (or equivalent) language cannot be finitely axiomatized as a first-order theory." Also, see theorem 4 of Tarski's Paper "What is Elementary Geometry?"